# How to create EC2 instance with two private IPs using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create 3 EC2 instances with two private IPs attached to eth0 and eth1 using terraform.

Can you suggest the correct Terraform resource I need to use to create and attach secondary private IP address' to each of the EC2 machines?

I know by default it creates eth0 and attaches a private IP address, I am looking to create eth1 as part of instance creation and attach a private IP from a different subnet.

```
resource "aws_instance" "test" {
  count = "${var.instance_count["test"]}"
   ami                    = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type          = "${var.instance_type}"
  key_name               = "${var.key_name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.kafka_sg.id}"]
  associate_public_ip_address = "${var.associate_public_ip_address}"
  ebs_optimized           = "${var.ebs_optimized}"
  disable_api_termination = "${var.disable_api_termination}"
  subnet_id              = "${var.subnet_id}"
  user_data                   = "${base64encode(file("${path.module}/mount.sh"))}"

  tags = {
        Name = "test-${var.instance_prefix}-${format("%02d", count.index+1)}"
    }

  root_block_device {
    volume_type           = "${var.root_volume_type}"
    volume_size           = "${var.root_volume_size}"

    }

  ebs_block_device{
      device_name = "/dev/sdb"
      volume_size = 10
      volume_type = "gp2"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an Elastic Network Interface to the server by creating the ENI via [aws_network_interface](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/network_interface.html), and then attaching it via [aws_network_interface_attachment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/network_interface_attachment.html)